# Flutter Cubit Not Updating UI for Language Change

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I'm encountering an issue with Cubit in Flutter. In my `main.dart`, I have initialized three providers: one for language, one for theme, and one for connectivity. Everything seems to be set up correctly, and I'm able to change the theme without any problems. However, when I try to change the language by executing `context.read<LanguageCubit>().changeLanguage(LANGUAGE.tr.name);` from the home screen, the language value changes internally but the UI does not update to reflect this change. This issue seems to be specific to the language Cubit; the theme changes are reflected on the UI as expected. What could be causing the language changes not to trigger a UI update?

Main.dart

```
  void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
  );

  final appRouter = AppRouter(); 
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale(LANGUAGE.en.name, ''),
        Locale(LANGUAGE.tr.name, ''),
      ],
      path: ApplicationConstants.LANG_ASSET_PATH,
      startLocale: Locale(LANGUAGE.tr.name, ''),
      child: MyApp(appRouter: appRouter),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({required this.appRouter, super.key});
  final AppRouter appRouter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => ThemeCubit()..getSavedTheme()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => LanguageCubit()..getSavedLanguage()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => ConnectivityCubit()),
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final languageCubit = context.watch<LanguageCubit>();
          final themeCubit = context.watch<ThemeCubit>();
          // final connectivityCubit = context.watch<ConnectivityCubit>();
          return MaterialApp.router(
            routeInformationParser: appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
            routerDelegate: appRouter.delegate(),
            localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
            supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
            locale: languageCubit.state.locale,
            theme: themeCubit.state.themeData,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            builder: CustomResponsive.build,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

languageCubit.dart

```
part 'language_state.dart';

class LanguageCubit extends Cubit<ChangeLanguageState> {
  LanguageCubit()
      : super(ChangeLanguageState(
            locale: Locale(ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE.name, '')));

  Future<void> getSavedLanguage() async {
    final cachedLanguageCode = await LanguageCacheHelper().getCachedLanguage();
    emit(ChangeLanguageState(locale: Locale(cachedLanguageCode, '')));
  }

  Future<void> changeLanguage(String languageCode) async {
    emit(ChangeLanguageState(locale: Locale(languageCode, '')));
  }
}
```

language_state.dart

```
part of 'language_cubit.dart';

class ChangeLanguageState {
  ChangeLanguageState({
    required this.locale,
  });
  final Locale locale;
}
```

home.dart

```
@RoutePage()
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}
class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(LocaleKeys.home_title.tr()),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<LanguageCubit>().changeLanguage(LANGUAGE.tr.name);
              print(context.read<LanguageCubit>().state.locale.toString());
              // context.setLocale(Locale('tr'));
            },
            child: Text(LocaleKeys.tr_lang.tr()),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<LanguageCubit>().changeLanguage(LANGUAGE.en.name);
              print(context.read<LanguageCubit>().state.locale.toString());
              // context.setLocale(Locale('en'));
            },
            child: Text(LocaleKeys.en_lang.tr()),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try override equals and hashcode for your ChangeLanguageState, or use equitable, or freezed.

Comment: I did all that, didn't get an error but still have the issue

Comment: context.setLocale() not working?

Comment: context.setLocale()  works, but if I used setLocale then what is the point of using the cubit

Answer (score 1):

Your state needs to extend `Equatable` and then you have to `override` props and pass there your state variables. Then, you should implement the `copyWith` pattern for your `ChangeLanguageState` to update the existent `ChangeLanguageState`.

Answer (score 0):

use the language code for your state.

for ex:

```
void changeLanguage(Locale locale) {
  currentLocale = locale;
  emit(LanguageChanged(locale.languageCode));
}

sealed class LocalizationState extends Equatable {
 const LocalizationState();
}

final class LanguageChanged extends LocalizationState {
 final String languageCode;

 const LanguageChanged(this.languageCode);
 @override
 List<Object> get props => [languageCode];
}
```

Then use it like that:

```
    var localizationCubit = context.read<LocalizationCubit>();
    var currentLocale= localizationCubit.currentLocale
```